# Magento - filtering customers based on an EAV (custom) attribute in RMA Grid

Tags: magento

I am using Magento 1.4.1.1 and the [AW RMA extension](http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/rma.html) over it.

With this extension installed I see an RMA requests grid and Pending RMA requests grid in admin.

I want to be able to filter requests in this grid based on an EAV (custom) attribute e.g., `customer_referrer_id` which is stored in *customer_entity_varchar*

The extension has a table *aw_rma_entity* in which it also keeps *customer_id*. The RMA Grid fetches data like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('awrma/entity')
                ->getCollection();
```

### ATTEMPT 1

I have attempted to join the customer entity with this table as follows:

```
$collection->getSelect()->join('customer_entity', 'customer_id = customer_entity.entity_id', array('entity_id' => 'customer_entity.entity_id'));
```

### RESULT 1

This just shows a page with no grid. If it had worked I would have then attempted to join customer_entity_varchar to apply the filter on the `customer_referrer_id` field.

---

### ATTEMPT 2

The other attempt I have made is to load the customer collection first and then join RMA entity data to it as in the following code:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection');

$collection->joinRight('awrma/entity', 'customer_id=entity_id', array('*'));
```

### RESULT 2

The second attempt generates the following error:

> Error Message--------------------------------> Item
>   (Mage_Customer_Model_Customer) with the same id "XXX" already exist";

This is despite of the fact that it had worked for me earlier in this way after a [similar question for filtering results in the Sales Orders Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915148/how-to-get-data-for-an-entity-for-example-customer-from-eav-attribute-table-to)

Comment: I would ask Ahead Works for support on this matter.

Comment: @FlorineChis I have asked them for help too, using their support forum, but haven't heard back from them yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably not the best solution, but it will most likely work:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('awrma/entity')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()->joinInner('customer_entity_varchar', 'customer_id=entity_id', array('attribute_id' =>'attribute_id','value'=>'value') );                
$logged_in_admin = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()->getEmail();  
$customer_referrer_attribute_id = //Set this equal to attribute_id FROM table eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = "customer_referrer_id"     
$collection->addFieldToFilter('attribute_id', $customer_referrer_attribute_id );
$collection->addFieldToFilter('value', $customer_referrer_id);
```