# Magento Customer Grid - Mask Email address

Tags: php, javascript, magento-1.4, magento

I have a requirement for call centre agents to search for a customer based on email address. But I don't want to show the email address in the customer grid unless they search for a email.

How can I do this??

Magento Version: 1.4.1.1

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a custom module that extend:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php
```

Read more @ [How to get data for an entity (for example customer) from eav_attribute table to be shown in Customer Grid for admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915148/how-to-get-data-for-an-entity-for-example-customer-from-eav-attribute-table-to)  (remove line with sales_order_grid)

Copy '_prepareColumns()' method to your custom module and change

```
    $this->addColumn('email', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Email'),
        'width'     => '150',
        'index'     => 'email'
        'renderer' = new MageIgniter_MaskEmail_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Data()  // added this line
    ));
```

Read more @ http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/192232/#t239222

Create Class:

```
 class MageIgniter_MaskEmail_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Data extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Action
 {
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
     {
         return $this->_getValue($row);
     }

     public function _getValue(Varien_Object $row)
     {
         $val = $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());  // row value

         $search_filter = base64_decode($this->getRequest()->getParam('filter'));
         // print_r($search_filter) : email=rs%40cs.com&customer_since%5Blocale%5D=en_US
         //read more @ http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/what-is-base64-encoding-and-how-can-we-benefit-from-it/

         // check if $search_filter contain email and equal to the search email
         parse_str($search_filter, $query)
         if(isset($query['email'] && $val == $query['email']){  // or array_key_exist()
            return $val;
         }
         else{
             return 'xxxxxxxx';
         }

     } 
 }
```

This is base off Magento v1.7

Comment: Apart from few syntax errors, your code works great. Thank you very much.

Comment: My code was untested... Could you post the syntax errors so I can update the code above