# Magento 1.7 - show order quantity in grid without decimals

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have this column definition in a grid for the ordered pieces of an order item:

```
        $this->addColumn('qty_ordered',
        array(
            'header'=> $this->__('Quantity'),
            'align' =>'right',
            'type=' => 'number',
            'index' => 'qty_ordered'
        )
    );
```

[xxx http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/6690/scr031.jpg](http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/6690/scr031.jpg)

How can I show the quantity without any decimals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a custom module

```
$this->addColumn('qty_ordered',
    array(
        'header'=> $this->__('Quantity'),
        'align' =>'right',
        'type=' => 'number',
        'index' => 'qty_ordered'
        'renderer' = new MageIgniter_RemoveQtyDecimals_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Date()
    )
);


 class MageIgniter_RemoveQtyDecimals_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Date extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Action
 {
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
     {
         return $this->_getValue($row);
     }

     public function _getValue(Varien_Object $row)
     {
         $val = $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
         return intval($val);

     } 
 }
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12695286/1191288

Answer (score 1):

I modified the sku array definition instead of creating qty_ordered.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass())
    ->join(
    'sales/order_item',
    '`sales/order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id',
        array(
            'skus'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat( `sales/order_item`.sku, "(", floor(`sales/order_item`.qty_ordered), ")" SEPARATOR ", ")'),
        ));
```

I believe you can use floor(`sales/order_item`.qty_ordered) on your qty_ordered definition as the same.

SKU column on Order Grid results something like:
MBA001(2), MOF004(1)